# Cannot access display component - Calling from Windows service

Tags: python, c++, c, go

I am running a service using "nssm". The nssm service starts an application which calls an exe. The exe is supposed to take a screenshot. The exe works fine when it is called by the application when the application runs as a stand alone. But the exe cannot access the display (doesn't work) when it is called by the application when the application runs as a service.

P.S. I have tried the screenshot exe using C, C++, Python, GoLang

Answer (score 0):

A Windows service (I assume you are talking about Windows) is for background processing, there is no UI attached to it. So I'm afraid it won't work regardless of what language you use.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it is *by design*: services by default have no access to the display. You must go into the control panel / Admin. tools / Computer management / Services. Then in the properties of a service, there is checkbox *Allow desktop interaction* in tab Connection. It must be checked to allow the service to access the display and by default it is unchecked.

Beware: names can be slightly off because my machine does not speak english...

Comment: I tried "Allow desktop interaction" and that does not work either. Because the exe is the one that needs desktop interaction, not the calling application.